# Laravel 6 change public_path()

Tags: laravel

I am trying to move the public folder to other place.

My laravel is in the subdomain folder.

[image]

Where can I set the variable for public_path()?

Steps I have tried:

```
`$app->bind('path.public', function() {
    return __DIR__;
});`

public function register()
{
    $this->app->bind('path.public', function() {
        return realpath(base_path().'/../../public_html');
    });
}

'disks' => [

'public' => [
   'driver' => 'local',
         'root' => env('PATH_PUBLIC'),
   'visibility' => 'public',
   'url' => env('SITE_ROOT'),
],
```

Comment: Are you sure that you've placed the first snippet of code (`$app->bind('path.public`...`) in your index.php file inside public directory?

Comment: yes. in public_html/index.php

$app->bind('path.public', function() {
    return __DIR__;
});